# How risky is it to disable security-policy enforcement before installing a driver?

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, apparmor, brother

I am trying to install a driver for my Brother printer/scanner (DCP-9020CDW). Brother provides Linux drivers (printer drivers are libre; scanner drivers are not). One of the [requirements](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/before.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on) before installing is to run

```
$sudo aa-complain cupsd
```

which, according to [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/aa-complain.8.html), means that "security policy is not enforced but rather access violations are logged to the system log".

Asking to disable security policies before installing new packages/drivers from outside the official repositories sounds suspicious to me. Am I being too paranoid, and is there anything sensible I can do apart from just not using my scanner*?

*There's an open-source PPD file for the printer, though I haven't tried installing it yet.

Comment: You are not being too paranoid. It's a bad idea. However, some manufacturers (including Brother) consider this bad-idea level of compatibility to be adequate. Other manufacturers do it much better.

Comment: @user535733, what in particular would be at risk in relation to cupsd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lack of any better answers, I've concluded that **it's a bad idea to disable security policies** unless one really understands or trusts the process. This might mean something cannot be installed or an alternative method is necessary.

In this case, I eventually managed to avoid using *aa-complain* by not using the Brother script that required this; instead, I manually installed the individual drivers and applied the changes that the script would do automatically (not describing the process here because it's not directly relevant to the question).